# How do i make an .exe that users can download on a website?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I already made an build pipeline with CI and i got  successful builds. I want my latest successful build to be released on a website where people can download an .exe file of the application. I find very little information about this on how to do this.

I am working with Azure DevOps.

Comment: Do you mean to convert the artifact into an exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your website upload method:

1. File share. Use the [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) or [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) in you build definition.
2. FTP or another. Try to use PowerShell to publish your results with [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops)